# I am unable to find from where the footer is coming in magento

Tags: magento

This is my web site http://sandlotwholesale.com/index.php/

I have to make come change in my footer. I try to make change in page/template/html/footer.phtml but changes are not reflecting even i deleted the footer file but still the footer is working. I dont know from where it is coming.

Please help me out ?

Comment: Sorry, can't resist: http://inchoo.net/fun-zone/the-inchooers-magento-developers-job-interview/

Answer (score 0):

You'll see the correct phtml-file by activating "Template Path Hints".

Go to System >> Configuration >> Developer

Change the "current configuration scope" to the actual store view

Activate Template Path Hints

After that all paths are shown in your frontend, just scroll down to your footer. Don't forget to undo these changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the admin panel you can go to system>configuration>developer(swich to website view -dropdown top left hand box)>template path hints>yes

this should show you where the template for the footer is.

Answer (score 0):

Always use template path hints to locate file addresses.
its System->configuration->Developer(Left Panel Tab) set it to YES and here you go.You will find the file locations accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using template path hints you can easily find your template path files.
Login to admin pannel and under

- System -> Configuration
- Change the “Configuration Scope” to “Default Store View” (or whichever store view you want to see template paths on)
- Under Advanced in the left menu click Developer
- Click “Debug” to expand that section
- Change “Template Path Hints”  to "Yes"
- Click Save Configuration
  Now to refresh the front-end and see all the locations of the template files so you can easily modify the correct ones. 
  Hope it will helps you.